# How do I synchronize my Facebook and Google+ Dragon Age Legends games?

Tags: dragon-age-legends

Is it possible to port my *Dragon Age: Legends* character from the Facebook version of the game to the Google+ version and keep them synchronized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You can't port them or synchronize them. From the [FAQ](http://dragonagelegends.com/faq/google/can-i-import-my-dragon-age-legends-hero-from-facebook-to-goo.html).

> **Can I import my Dragon Age Legends hero from Facebook to Google+?**
>
> No.
> The Facebook and Google+ versions of Dragon Age Legends are completely
> independent of each other. If you've already played the game on
> Facebook, you're able to create a brand-new hero on Google+. Try
> playing as another class for a very different DAL experience!

Comment: That sucks. It's a flash game, so I _don't_ want the tedium of playing it over.

Comment: @CyberSkull Yeah. You would think in the end, it's using the same data storage for both. Maybe they improved on the Google+ one or something.

Comment: I suspect that each game is stored on the local servers for the service.